# i would love to know what this annoying feature of IDEA is --- so that I can turn it off

Tags: scala, intellij-idea

Code can explain this better than I can:

```
// how do i make IntelliJ IDEA *stop doing this* to my code?

case class Person(
                   name: String,
                   age: Int,
                   gender: Gender
                   )

                   // it's annoying!
```

Comment: What exactly is it doing that you don't like??

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is a code style setting, just disable it in the prefs:

Code Style -> Scala -> Wrapping and Braces -> Method declaration parameters -> Align when multiline.